# BLE Device disconnected when calling via Handsfree profile on iOS with reason 722

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, disconnect

We develop our own BLE device and connect to a iPhone. We discover an issue that it will disconnect after 2~3 minutes when making parallel calls over HFP. (ex: Using car audio system,infotainment HUD or so).

Does anyone know what status `722` stands for. How do we resolve this?
Thanks.

#### step

1. `iPhone` connect to `Our Device` (continiously collecting data in background mode.)
2. `iPhone` connect to `Car Audio Systems`
3. `iPhone` make a call with IM app (over HFP).
4. after 2 ~ 3 mins, the connection between `iPhone` and `Our Device` disconnect due to reason `722`.

#### sysdiagnose log

```
default 2021-02-09 17:04:57.813721 +0800    bluetoothd  Server.LE.Connection    LE Link disconnected for handle 0x14c804720 address <private> with reason 722 encryptionPending 0
default 2021-02-09 17:04:57.813774 +0800    bluetoothd  Server.LE.Connection    LE ConnManager disconnection complete reason 722 address=<private> localRole=Master
default 2021-02-09 17:04:57.816296 +0800    bluetoothd  Stack.GATT   _GATT_LE_DisconnectedCB on handle 0x000000014C804720 with reason  STATUS 722
default 2021-02-09 17:04:57.816977 +0800    bluetoothd  Server.LE   Device "E2278A91-B7B6-2122-696C-BE887487C8D7" set last connected time to 1612890297
default 2021-02-09 17:04:57.820707 +0800    bluetoothd  Stack.CL     Removing peer ID 0 for handle 0x000000014C804720
default 2021-02-09 17:04:57.820869 +0800    bluetoothd  Stack.HCI    Releasing LE connection 0x0041
default 2021-02-09 17:04:57.822551 +0800    bluetoothd  Server.LE.Connection    Device "E2278A91-B7B6-2122-696C-BE887487C8D7" does not require low latency
default 2021-02-09 17:04:57.822580 +0800    bluetoothd  Server.LE.Connection    Found link-ready device calling disconnection notification
default 2021-02-09 17:04:57.822582 +0800    bluetoothd  Server.LE.Connection    Disconnected from device "E2278A91-B7B6-2122-696C-BE887487C8D7" successfully (locally-initiated)
default 2021-02-09 17:04:57.822585 +0800    bluetoothd  Server.LE.Connection    linkReady:1 disconnectDevice:0 localRole:0 reason:722 result:0
default 2021-02-09 17:04:57.824928 +0800    bluetoothd  Server.LE.Security  Removing temporary security keys for device <private>
```

Comment: BLE Handsfree Profile? HFP does not exist for Bluetooth Low Energy, it is a Bluetooth Classic Profile. Do you mean that your BLE device disconnects if you're making parallel calls over HFP using the phone?

Comment: Yes. I will modifiy my description.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: You enabled the BLE connection, made a call over HFP for 2-3 minutes and the BLE connection dropped after that time?

Comment: @M.Kotzjan Hi, I clarify the description again.